# How do you distinguish your EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, instances

The ec2-describe-instances command is not very helpful in distinguishing the instances.
Are there command line tools that give a better overview?

Perhaps somewhat like http://github.com/newbamboo/manec2 but with support for different regions etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon recently has added a feature to 'tag' your EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use security group to identify your instance. See http://www.shlomoswidler.com/2009/06/tagging-ec2-instances-using-security_30.html

You can add an empty  security_group to each instance to be able to communicate with each other.

I'm using http://github.com/cocoy/mr.awsome to provision and name instance via security groups. This way I can identify each instance whether I'm using Elasticfox, AWS console, or the same tool mr.awsome.

See also: http://www.capsunlock.net/2010/05/five-easy-steps-to-tag-ec2-instance-using-mr-awsome.html

Cheers,

Rodney

http://www.capunlock.net

Answer (score 1):

I think Rodney's method of using securty groups is the most comprehensive, but if you just want a way to assign a free-form tag to your instances, you can do that if you set up a free account at [RightScale](http://rightscale.com) and use it to launch your instances.  Warning - you'll have to put up with occasional emails from RightScale asking if you want to use their paid services.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a command-line solution, and it's far from perfect, but my company currently maintains a shared Word document in a Dropbox folder that maintains the role/name -> instance id mapping for all of our active instances.

Using a Word document also allows us to keep track of some more information that is nice to have available at a glance:

- The "environment" the instance is a part of.
- The RDP shortcut to the instance for simple access.
- The AMI the instance was launched from.
- Any additional attached volumes.
- The region the instance is in.
- etc.